# The proper way to store bits in JK flip flops

Tags: flipflop, pulldown

Currently I'm working on a contraption where when a button is pushed, it briefly creates a 4 bit binary sequence.  I want to have this binary sequence, 0000 all the way up to 1111, stored properly in 4 JK flip flops.  The problem I am having is how to properly invoke the clock and store the bits.

I would assume that I need to use the button as a clock pulse, but the problem is, if the binary code is 0000, it would be near impossible to accurately find if the button is held down, especially since I'm using pull-down resistors that hold inputs J and K to ground so that they function properly if the button is not being pushed.

Here is a diagram of what I am attempting:

[image: img]

EDIT: It seems to me that registers will be the way to go.  I must test some more things.

EDIT1: I've decided to not rely on the button pulses, and just sync everything using an astable multivibrator

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to understand your question, but I'm going to guess that you mean that you have (up to) 16 different buttons, and you want the flip-flops to retain the binary value corresponding to the last button pressed.

The concept that you are missing is that of a "strobe" signal. This additional signal would be created by whatever circuit is producing the binary encodings for the buttons, and it indicates that at least one button is being pressed. Even if the encoding for one of the buttons is "0000", the strobe signal will be asserted, and can be used to update the flip-flops.

I'm not sure why you're presupposing the use of JK-type flip-flops. Normally, D-type flip-flops would be used in this sort of application.

Comment: Not what I mean, I have a single button that generates a random 4 bit binary output.  As for the use of JK-type flip-flops, I was unable to find much information on this matter, so I assumed that JK flip-flops would be a good starting point.  I will do some research on D-type flip-flops.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, in any case, your random number generator also needs to generate a strobe signal each time the button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will make sure to attach a strobe signal to the binary so that the flip flop can tell if the button is pressed.